# Connect collection of rows from one table to another table's column - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

As you save from the image, I have a `Packing` and a `Product` table. I want to somehow connect some rows from the product table to the `Productlist` column of `Packing` table, so that in future I can add packing in the database and write  also what products I have in this packing. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Product List has multiple values in it you should not store them in a single column in the table.  You should create a separate table that has PackingTableID and Product  so in this new table you would have multiple Products tied to one Package.  Then you would join to that table.  (a one to many relationship).

Similar to this:

```
Select PackingTable.PackingTableID , ProductTable.PackageName
From PackingTable
INNER JOIN PackingTableProducts ON PackingTable.PackingTableID = PackingTableProducts.PackingTableID
INNER JOIN ProductTable ON PackingTableProducts.ProductID = ProductTable.ProductID
```

Comment: in the place of PackageTableID, it should be PackingTableProducts?

Comment: I mistyped the tablename in the select field, updating

Comment: This is all sudo code as well, since you would have to create the new PackingTableProducts table and the relationships there.  So this may not be exactly what you would use, I just did this as an example